# Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleSidebar is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

im getting this " Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleSidebar is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick " error when im trying to open my sidebar. 
It worked in codepen but on my site it doesnt seem to work! 
My site : Skintheft.com/SufferSite

Index code sample --

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul>  

    <li>Home </li>
    <li>Contact </li>
    <li>About </li>

    </ul>
```

css file :

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}


#sidebar { 
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  background:#727e87;
  left:-200px;
  transition: all 250ms linear;

}

#sidebar.active {
    left:0px;
}

#sidebar ul li {
  color:rgba(230,230,230,0.9);
  list-style:none;
  padding:15px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
    position:absolute;
    left:230px;
    top:20px;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn span {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:5px; 
    background:#727e87;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

and last but not least the javascript

```
function toggleSidebar(){
    document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle('active');
}
```

I personally don't have any idea on how to fix this, i would deeply appreciate any help! thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided works perfectly fine. The only problem I can see in your website is the below JS you provided is wrapped in quotes in the website, please change it and the toggle will work fine.

I am talking about the below code.

**JS Before:**

```
"
function toggleSidebar() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle('active');
}
"
```

**JS After:**

```
<script>
function toggleSidebar() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle('active');
}
</script>
```

The reason you are getting the error is because in the HTML.

```
<div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
```

it is searching for the below function, but its unable to find it.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #727e87;
  left: -200px;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}

#sidebar.active {
  left: 0px;
}

#sidebar ul li {
  color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.9);
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  top: 20px;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #727e87;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul>

    <li>Home </li>
    <li>Contact </li>
    <li>About </li>

  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! i fixed it!:P

Comment: thanks! but the only thing now is that the code snippet is showing on the bottom of the screen xd, do you have any idea on how i can remove/hide this?